# Resuming Python after Tar SSH Pipe shell call?

Tags: python, ssh, pipe, tar

I'm transferring custom maptiles (like for google maps) from my home server to a cloud server. The fastest way I can transfer them seems to be the tar ssh pipe method.

```
tar czpf - ./tiles | ssh -i myprivate.key user@ssh.example.com "tar xzpf - -C /www/tiles/"
```

This works great on the command line, but now I want my python script that creates the tiles to push them automatically. I've tried:

```
os.system('tar czpf - ./tiles | ssh -i myprivate.key user@ssh.example.com "tar xzpf - -C /www/tiles/"')
```

as well as the subrprocess.Popen variation, and they both copy all my map tiles to the remote server, but the system shell doesn't close and return control to the python script and so the script hangs and does not complete.

I'm guess there's something going on with the pipe or tar redirect to STDOUT that doesn't let the os.system complete. I was thinking perhaps the remote tar that is responsible for the uncompress is waiting for more STDIN through the pipe, but nothing else is coming?  I really don't know too much about this and appreciate your help.

Is there something different I can do to get the rest of the script to complete, while still being able to realize the benefits of the tar ssh pipe transfer method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.system() is deprecated in favour of the subprocess module.

I ran this in a Python 2.7 interpreter. It succeeded and immediately returned control:

```
import subprocess
try:
    if subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "tar_ssh.sh"]) == 0:
        print "success!"
    else:
        print "failed! :("
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

It calls **tar_ssh.sh** which simply contains your command (assumes public key authentication, not passphrase authentication):

```
tar czpf - ./source_folder/ | ssh username@ip_or_hostname "tar xzpf - -C /destination_folder/"
```

Comment: Doh! I'm just stupid.  My code was also spinning up a mutliprocessing queue, and in my testing I had commented out the code to shut it down. Once I used your code I could see that was the case. Thank you!

Comment: @pilotandy Ahh okay, that explains it! Glad you got it working :)